# How to set text after height 50px then extra text will become 5 fullstop ... in Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image: Sample] >>>>>>>>>**[Sample Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-sea-ti879r?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:56-836)**

```
   <div style="height:50px">
        
        
        
   </div>
```

Comment: @bassxzero forgot save just now i updated the sandbox already thank you.

Comment: I think you are talking about adding ellipsis for overflow text. Try this. `<div style="height:50px; text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @bassxzero yes, need add --webkit-line-clamp to let div show only 2 or 3 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` can fix this for you. Also having height equally divisible by the line-height works well visually.

```css
.setheight {
    height: 50px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="setheight">
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Deva - I made your code a snippet (the `<>` button). Also added line-height 25px so that height 50px is evenly divisible.